# Async actions that don't dispatch to the store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my React/Redux app, I have a component that needs to fetch something from the server, so I've written the simple axios call as a redux thunk action.

However, that action doesn't dispatch anything itself; the information fetched is used ONLY in the component. So it doesn't actually need to be a redux action. Right?

It's possible that I jumped into learning Redux so soon after I got acquainted with React that I...don't know where you're "supposed" to put async functions besides in Redux actions.

Do I just make the axios call in an instance method in my Component? What is best practice with this?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, you can make the request in your component. Since you probably want to re-render something based on the response, you will want to use setState in your class component or useState in your function component. It is recommended though to have an abstraction layer in-between your component and the http client (axios). Some sort of service module for example, that returns the axios promise. In your component you can either await the response or put a .then handler on the promise, which then sets component state.